# How do i use the query in google sheets to return N results from each tab

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

How do I use the query in Google Sheets to return N results from each tab.

So I have this formula:

```
=QUERY({sheet1!A2:D;sheet2!A2:D}; "select * where Col4>=65 order by Col4 desc Limit 3")
```

But what I want is that the results to be limited to 3 but from each individual sheet tab so I have displayed **3 results from sheet1 and 3 from sheet2**.

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following

```
={QUERY({sheet1!A2:D}; "select * where Col4>=65 order by Col4 desc Limit 3"),
  QUERY({sheet2!A2:D}; "select * where Col4>=65 order by Col4 desc Limit 3")}
```

***(do adjust syntax according to your locale)***

Comment: ok i see that i have just two questions,  1. I want the results overall to be sorted by Col4 as I see this formula it will display first sheet1 and order by col4 then sheet2 on order by col4 it will not be an overall sort but by sheet by sheet ; 2. is this the only option ? because I listed here 2 sheets but I may need to use a lot more so it will get kinda to a long formula. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Oh and i just found out another problem, if for example any of the sheets has no data to be pulled then I get an error on the main sheet "#VALUE! ( In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows. )"

Answer (score 1):

Well hello, after much trial and error I managed to get a formula that does exactly what I want there is just one simple problem it's so long .... but maybe it can help others too or someone can come up with a way to simplify it.

```
=SORT(IFERROR({iferror(query({sheet1!A2:D}; "select * where Col4>=65 order by Col4 desc Limit 3";0);A2:D2/0); iferror(query({sheet2!A2:D}; "select * where Col4>=65 order by Col4 desc Limit 3";0);A2:D2/0)});4;0)
```

This formula will display 3 results from each tab like I wanted and will sort it overall all the data displayed but like I said it's very long already and if I want to add more tabs it will get even longer. But it's the only solution I could come up with that does everything I needed automatically. I hope it can help people and if there is someone who can simplify it that would be an even greater help.

Comment: Glad you worked it out. Kudos. Remember you can also accept your own answer.